# Is it possible to use multithreading for hyperparameter tuning with keras?

Tags: multithreading, keras, tensorflow2.0, hyperparameters

Since hyperparameter tuning seems to consist in training different models for the same task, I suppose it is a good idea to train them in parallel in order to gain some time. However, my attempt was quite unsuccessful, as multiple errors occured during the execution of my code. I was wondering if using keras requires me to write multithreading differently, or if the problem lies elsewhere.

Here's what I wrote (I'm trying to calculate the effect of dropout on the minimal value of a custom metric) :

```
from threading import Thread

class FitModel(Thread):

    def __init__(self, params):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.params = params

    def run(self):
        DC=DeltaCallback(verbose=0)  #custom metric
    
        model=keras.models.Sequential([
            keras.layers.Conv1D(64,11,activation="relu",padding="SAME",input_shape=(700,1)),
            keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
            keras.layers.AvgPool1D(pool_size=2),
            keras.layers.Conv1D(128,11,activation="relu",padding="SAME"),
            keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
            keras.layers.AvgPool1D(pool_size=2),
            keras.layers.Conv1D(256,11,activation="relu",padding="SAME"),
            keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
            keras.layers.AvgPool1D(pool_size=2),
            keras.layers.Conv1D(512,11,activation="relu",padding="SAME"),
            keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
            keras.layers.AvgPool1D(pool_size=2),
            keras.layers.Conv1D(512,11,activation="relu",padding="SAME"),
            keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
            keras.layers.AvgPool1D(pool_size=2),
            keras.layers.Flatten(),
            keras.layers.Dropout(self.params[0]),
            keras.layers.Dense(4096,activation="relu"),
            keras.layers.Dropout(self.params[1]),
            keras.layers.Dense(4096,activation="relu"),
            keras.layers.Dense(256,activation="softmax")
        ])
        model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
             optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.00001),
             metrics=["accuracy"])

        model.fit(X_train,y_train,batch_size=100,epochs=50,validation_data=(X_valid,y_valid),callbacks=[DC],verbose=2)

        print(self.params,"epochs : ",DC.deltas.index(min(DC.deltas)))
        print(self.params,"deltamin : ",DC.deltas[DC.deltas.index(min(DC.deltas))])
        print(self.params,"Nval : ", DC.Nvals[DC.deltas.index(min(DC.deltas))])

        
parameters_list=[[0,0.1],[0.1,0],[0.2,0],[0.1,0.2],[0.2,0.1],[0.3,0],[0.3,0.1],[0.3,0.2],[0,0.3],[0.1,0.3],[0.2,0.3]]
    
# create threads
THREADS = [FitModel(parameters) for parameters in parameters_list]
    
# start threads
for thread in THREADS:
    thread.start()

# wait for threads to finish
for thread in THREADS:
    thread.join()
```

The problem is that multiple Exceptions occur when I try to execute this code, as well as OOM errors. Any idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

I see that it is an older question but I will still answer in case someone else might need an answer.

There are two ways. The first is use keras_tuner Hypermodel for performing hyper parameter tuning.

https://keras.io/guides/keras_tuner/getting_started/

Im not as familiar with this but I do know there are methods for using multiple threads for keras_tuner. If you then use random search, grid search or hyperband you can do parameter search.

I am more familiar with scikit-learn estimators.
Since you already made a class implementation with run you could change it to fit. Then you can use baseEstimator

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html

I believe keras has its own predict function but it uses evaluate for scoring. So I think you would have to implement your own scoring function for your class that just calls evaluate on your fitted model. Then you can use RandomSearchCV or GridSearchCV from Scikit-Learn with n_jobs to how many threads you want.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html